# error in production, but site working Cannot find corresponding module, type declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

What would be this error that occurs in production, on my machine it works, but in production it points out this

src/controllers/userController.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/UserService' or its corresponding type declarations.

I've already looked at the file names to see if there is a difference in upper or lower case letters, but everything appears to be ok, I'll leave the repository link

https://github.com/FabioPenedo/backend-desafio2

I tried to check if there was a difference in the name of the files with upper and lower case letters, I tried to import in other ways, but it was successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the import on user controller is wrong,it should be:

```js
import { userService } from '../services/UserService';
```

Comment: In fact, I've already tried this both ways, before it was with UserService, I changed it to userService because I saw that this could be the problem, start with the saved letter

Comment: If you have changed the file name between two commit maybe that's the problem. May you try to create a new file with the name of the service that you like, different from UserService, just to try, and copy test all data on it and of course delete the other one. Git has problems with case-sensitive stuff. Let me know in case

Comment: Or you can try [that](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/git-basics-help-my-case-sensitive-filename-changes-dont-commit/)